# JSON JOLT, take first array and then take second array

Tags: json, jolt

I have a problem. I have an object from which I take data, merge it and then display it, but now I found out that the object can be duplicated and now I need to merge data for one object and then for the other.

Here is a JSON Input:

```
{
  
}
```

Here is the JOLT spec that I have created:

```
[
  {
   
    }
]
```

I have this result:

```
{
 
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: But this question is not that I've already answered ...

Answer (score 1):

The following spec will work for you. I assume you need to display the value only if `decision.value[0]= "01"`. Let me know if that is not the case.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "X": {
        "Decisions": {
          "Decision": {
            "*": {
              "DetailsPensionPaymentPeriods": {
                "*": {
                  "PensionAmount": {
                    "bk34": "=concat(@(1,grossAmount),'; ',@(2,currency.value[0]),'; ',@(2,paymentFrequency.value[0]))"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "@X.Decisions.Decision[0]": {
        "DetailsPensionPaymentPeriods": {
          "*": {
            "PensionAmount": {
              "@(3,decision.value[0])": {
                "01": {
                  "@(5,actualStartDatePensionPaymentsFromInstitution)": "p1.awardedPensionDecisions.awardedPensionDecision.paymentDetails.paymentDetail[&4].bk33",
                  "@(2,bk34)": "p1.awardedPensionDecisions.awardedPensionDecision.paymentDetails.paymentDetail[&4].bk34"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

Comment: This is a really great solution, but I have a problem. Here I gave only part of the transform that covers what I wanted, but when I try to add your solution to the rest, it doesn't work. If I were to pass the entire transformation here as a comment, would you be able to add it to the rest?

Comment: Edit the question and post what you are expecting. I will try to give you the solution

Comment: I replaced it with what I need

Comment: Can anything be done about it?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the expected result where you merge data for multiple objects, you need to iterate through the Decision array and create multiple output objects. You can do this using Jolt's `shift` operation combined with looping constructs. Below is the modified JOLT spec that should give you the desired result:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "X.Decisions.Decision[0].DetailsPensionPaymentPeriods": {
        "*": {
          "PensionAmount": {
            "grossAmount": "p1.awardedPensionDecisions.awardedPensionDecision.paymentDetails.paymentDetail[&1].bk34",
            "currency": {
              "value": {
                "0": "p1.awardedPensionDecisions.awardedPensionDecision.paymentDetails.paymentDetail[&1].bk34Currency"
              }
            },
            "paymentFrequency": {
              "value": {
                "0": "p1.awardedPensionDecisions.awardedPensionDecision.paymentDetails.paymentDetail[&1].bk34Frequency"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "X.Decisions.Decision[0].actualStartDatePensionPaymentsFromInstitution": "p1.awardedPensionDecisions.awardedPensionDecision.paymentDetails.paymentDetail[0].bk33"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "p1.awardedPensionDecisions.awardedPensionDecision.paymentDetails.paymentDetail[0].bk34": "=concat(@(1,p1.awardedPensionDecisions.awardedPensionDecision.paymentDetails.paymentDetail[0].bk34), ', ', @(2,p1.awardedPensionDecisions.awardedPensionDecision.paymentDetails.paymentDetail[1].bk34))"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Actualy when i try your solution is returned: Error running the Transform.

JOLT Chainr encountered an exception constructing Transform className:com.bazaarvoice.jolt.Shiftr at index:0.

Invalid ArrayPathElement key:currency.value[0]

Comment: And i wanted merge all bk34 in one data

Comment: the problem is with currency.value

Comment: I've edited my answer try the last part

Comment: Now it return this: Error running the Transform.

JOLT Chainr encountered an exception constructing Transform className:com.bazaarvoice.jolt.Shiftr at index:0.

Invalid ArrayPathElement key:value[0]

Comment: one more try run the above

Comment: Now this return: null

Comment: last one, hope this one works

Comment: This one doesn't work either: Error running the Transform.

JOLT Chainr encountered an exception constructing Transform className:com.bazaarvoice.jolt.Shiftr at index:0.

Invalid ArrayPathElement key:X.Decisions.Decision[0].DetailsPensionPaymentPeriods

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following transformation as an option

```json
[
  { // construct the innermost array "PaymentDetail"
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@Decisions.Decision": {
          "*": {
            "DetailsPensionPaymentPeriods": {
              "*": {
                "@2,actualStartDatePensionPaymentsFromInstitution": "PaymentDetail[&].bk33",
                "@PensionAmount.grossAmount": "PaymentDetail[&].bk34",
                "@currency.value|@paymentFrequency.value": {
                  "*": "PaymentDetail[&1].bk34"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*4": "=join('; ',@(1,&))" // semi-colon separartedly concatenate components of bk34
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // add upper nodes to the "PaymentDetail" array
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "@": "Y.awardedPensionDecisions.awardedPensionDecision.paymentDetails"
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand the conditions you added in the spec. I just modified only the part where you need a list of items in your existing spec.
The below spec can make the change.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "P6000": {
        "LocalCaseNumbers": {
          "LocalCaseNumber": {
            "*": {
              "Institution": {
                "bk31x": "=concat(@(1,institutionName),'; ',@(2,caseNumber),'; ',@(5,InsuredPerson.PersonIdentification.PINPersonInEachInstitution.PersonalIdentificationNumber[0].personalIdentificationNumber),'; ',@(5,AdditionalInformationDecision.dateWhenDecisionIssuedStatedDecision))"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "Decisions": {
          "Decision": {
            "*": {
              "DetailsPensionPaymentPeriods": {
                "*": {
                  "PensionAmount": {
                    "bk34": "=concat(@(1,grossAmount),'; ',@(2,currency.value[0]),'; ',@(2,paymentFrequency.value[0]))"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "AdditionalInformationDecision": {
          "InformationRightAReview": {
            "WhereAddressReview": {
              "*": {
                "Institution": {
                  "bk38x": "=concat(@(1,institutionName),'; ',@(2,Address.street),'; ',@(2,Address.buildingName),'; ',@(2,Address.town),'; ',@(2,Address.postalCode),'; ',@(2,Address.country.value[0]))"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "Reductions": {
          "ReductionsPension": {
            "*": {
              "size1": "=size(@(1,pensionReducedPursuantOverlappingBenefitsSameKind))",
              "size2": "=size(@(1,pensionReducedPursuantOverlappingOrBenefitsOrIncome))"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "@(0,P6000.Decisions.Decision[0].decision.value[0])": {
        "01": {
          "@(2,P6000.LocalCaseNumbers.LocalCaseNumber[0].Institution.bk31x)": "p1.awardedPensionDecisions.awardedPensionDecision.bk31",
          "@(2,P6000.Decisions.Decision[0].typePension.value[0])": {
            "01": {
              "#1": "p1.awardedPensionDecisions.awardedPensionDecision.bk32"
            },
            "02": {
              "#2": "p1.awardedPensionDecisions.awardedPensionDecision.bk32"
            },
            "03": {
              "#3": "p1.awardedPensionDecisions.awardedPensionDecision.bk32"
            },
            "04": {
              "#2": "p1.awardedPensionDecisions.awardedPensionDecision.bk32"
            },
            "05": {
              "#2": "p1.awardedPensionDecisions.awardedPensionDecision.bk32"
            },
            "06": {
              "#1": "p1.awardedPensionDecisions.awardedPensionDecision.bk32"
            }
          },
          "@(2,P6000.Decisions.Decision[0].DetailsPensionPaymentPeriods)": {
            "*": {
              "PensionAmount": {
                "@(6,P6000.Decisions.Decision[0].actualStartDatePensionPaymentsFromInstitution)": "p1.awardedPensionDecisions.awardedPensionDecision.paymentDetails.paymentDetail[&2].bk33",
                "bk34": "p1.awardedPensionDecisions.awardedPensionDecision.paymentDetails.paymentDetail[&2].&"
              }
            }
          },
          "@(2,P6000.Decisions.Decision[0].awardBenefitArticle.value[0])": {
            "01": {
              "#4": "p1.awardedPensionDecisions.awardedPensionDecision.bk35"
            },
            "02": {
              "#5": "p1.awardedPensionDecisions.awardedPensionDecision.bk35"
            },
            "03": {
              "#6": "p1.awardedPensionDecisions.awardedPensionDecision.bk35"
            },
            "04": {
              "#6": "p1.awardedPensionDecisions.awardedPensionDecision.bk35"
            }
          },
          "@(2,P6000.Reductions.ReductionsPension[0].size1)": {
            "0": {
              "@(5,P6000.Reductions.ReductionsPension[0].size2)": {
                "0": {
                  "": "p1.awardedPensionDecisions.awardedPensionDecision.bk36"
                },
                "*": {
                  "#7": "p1.awardedPensionDecisions.awardedPensionDecision.bk36"
                }
              }
            },
            "*": {
              "#7": "p1.awardedPensionDecisions.awardedPensionDecision.bk36"
            }
          },
          "@(2,P6000.LocalCaseNumbers.LocalCaseNumber[0].country.value[0])": {
            "PL": {
              "#w każdym czasie": "p1.awardedPensionDecisions.awardedPensionDecision.bk37"
            },
            "*": {
              "": "p1.awardedPensionDecisions.awardedPensionDecision.bk37"
            }
          },
          "@(2,P6000.AdditionalInformationDecision.InformationRightAReview.WhereAddressReview[0].Institution.bk38x)": "p1.awardedPensionDecisions.awardedPensionDecision.bk38",
          "# ": "p1.awardedPensionDecisions.awardedPensionDecision. "
        },
        "02": {
          "@(2,P6000.LocalCaseNumbers.LocalCaseNumber[0].Institution.bk31x)": "p1.rejectedPensionDecisions.rejectedPensionDecision.bk41",
          "@(2,P6000.Decisions.Decision[0].typePension.value[0])": {
            "01": {
              "#1": "p1.rejectedPensionDecisions.rejectedPensionDecision.bk42"
            },
            "02": {
              "#2": "p1.rejectedPensionDecisions.rejectedPensionDecision.bk42"
            },
            "03": {
              "#3": "p1.rejectedPensionDecisions.rejectedPensionDecision.bk42"
            },
            "04": {
              "#2": "p1.rejectedPensionDecisions.rejectedPensionDecision.bk42"
            },
            "05": {
              "#2": "p1.rejectedPensionDecisions.rejectedPensionDecision.bk42"
            },
            "06": {
              "#1": "p1.rejectedPensionDecisions.rejectedPensionDecision.bk42"
            }
          },
          "@(2,P6000.Decisions.Decision[0].RejectionReasons[0].rejectionReasons.value[0])": {
            "01": {
              "#4": "p1.rejectedPensionDecisions.rejectedPensionDecision.bk43"
            },
            "02": {
              "#5": "p1.rejectedPensionDecisions.rejectedPensionDecision.bk43"
            },
            "03": {
              "#6": "p1.rejectedPensionDecisions.rejectedPensionDecision.bk43"
            },
            "04": {
              "#7": "p1.rejectedPensionDecisions.rejectedPensionDecision.bk43"
            },
            "05": {
              "#8": "p1.rejectedPensionDecisions.rejectedPensionDecision.bk43"
            },
            "06": {
              "#9": "p1.rejectedPensionDecisions.rejectedPensionDecision.bk43"
            },
            "07": {
              "#10": "p1.rejectedPensionDecisions.rejectedPensionDecision.bk43"
            },
            "08": {
              "#10": "p1.rejectedPensionDecisions.rejectedPensionDecision.bk43"
            },
            "99": {
              "#10": "p1.rejectedPensionDecisions.rejectedPensionDecision.bk43"
            }
          },
          "@(2,P6000.LocalCaseNumbers.LocalCaseNumber[0].country.value[0])": {
            "PL": {
              "#w każdym czasie": "p1.rejectedPensionDecisions.rejectedPensionDecision.bk44"
            },
            "*": {
              "": "p1.rejectedPensionDecisions.rejectedPensionDecision.bk44"
            }
          },
          "@(2,P6000.AdditionalInformationDecision.InformationRightAReview.WhereAddressReview[0].Institution.bk38x)": "p1.rejectedPensionDecisions.rejectedPensionDecision.bk45",
          "# ": "p1.rejectedPensionDecisions.rejectedPensionDecision. "
        }
      }
    }
    }
]
```

[image]

Comment: @Danon Is this working for you?